# Problems with installation of MinionPro

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive

I am trying run my .tex-file after I [installed](http://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2007/12/11/installing-minion-pro-fonts/) MinionPro in TeXLive, but the following problem appears:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file MinionPro-Bold.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file
 for reading
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help me out. (I am extremely new to LaTeX)

Furthermore the [installation](http://carlo-hamalainen.net/blog/2007/12/11/installing-minion-pro-fonts/) wants my path to adobefonts:

```
find /youradobefonts/ -iname '*minion*pro*otf' -exec cp -v '{}' otf/ ';'
```

but I don't know where they are.

Comment: Do you have the MinionPro-Fonts somewhere? The used to ship with Adobe Reader (together with MyriadPro). If you don't have the fonts, the script won’t find them.

Comment: I installed the acroread package, but cann't find these fonts. Which package I have to install and where it'll be located?

Comment: Which OS do you use? On Ubuntu the fonts should be in `/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Resource/Font/`. On Windows somewhere in the `Program Files\Adobe` directory.

Comment: If you have problems with certain symbols such as $\epsilon$ and $\varepsilon$, you can try [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro), which is based on the MinionPro package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Tobias Schula. I just used the wrong Font path for the Adobefonts. After I repeat the the installation with the right path `/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Resource/Font/` everything worked fine for me again.